# Flask-Restx not converting enum field type to JSON

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, flask-restx

I need help with Enum field type as it is not accepted by Swagger and I am getting error message `**TypeError: Object or Type eGameLevel is not JSON serializable**`. Below is the complete set of code for table. Complete set of code with DB table and sqlalchemy settings is provided. I already tried it with Marshmallow-Enum Flask package and it didn't worked. Looking for kind help with some explanation about the solution so I can learn it well. :-)

I am using MySQL with the Flask. In Postgres its pretty easy to manage all the choice fields. All I need is a working example or a link to repository where MySQL choice fields are showing up in swagger drop down.

## My Model:

```
import enum
from app import db
from typing import List


class eGameLevel(enum.Enum):
    BEGINNER    =   'Beginner'
    ADVANCED    =   'Advanced'


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game_stage'

    id                              = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    game_level= db.Column(db.Enum(eGameLevel), 
             default=eGameLevel.BEGINNER, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='game__level_submissions', lazy=True)

def __init__(self, game_level, user_id):
    self.game_level = game_level
    self.user_id = user_id

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Game(game_level%s, ' \
           'user_id%s'%(self.game_level,
                        self.user_id)
def json(self):
    return {'game_level':self.game_level,
            'user_id':self.user_id}

@classmethod
def by_game_id(cls, _id):
    return cls.query.filter_by(id=_id)

@classmethod
def find_by_game_level(cls, game_level):
    return cls.query.filter_by(game_level=game_level)

@classmethod
def by_user_id(cls, _user_id):
    return cls.query.filter_by(user_id=_user_id)

@classmethod
def find_all(cls) -> List["Game"]:
    return cls.query.all()

def save_to_db(self) -> None:
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()

def delete_from_db(self) -> None:
    db.session.delete(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

## My Schema

```
from app import ma
from app.models import Gode

class GameSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    game = ma.Nested('GameSchema', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model =  Game
        load_instance = True
        include_fk= True
```

## My Resources:

```
from flask_restx import Resource, fields, Namespace
from app.models import Game
from app import db
from app.schemas import GameSchema

GAME_REQUEST_NOT_FOUND = "Game request not found."
GAME_REQUEST_ALREADY_EXSISTS = "Game request '{}' Already exists."

game_ns = Namespace('Game', description='Available Game Requests')
games_ns = Namespace('Game Requests', description='All Games Requests')


game_schema = GameSchema()
games_list_schema = GameSchema(many=True)


gamerequest = game_ns.model('Game', {
    'game_level': fields.String('Game Level: Must be one of: BEGINNER, ADVANCED.'),
    'user_id': fields.Integer,

})


class GameRequestsListAPI(Resource):
    @games_ns.doc('Get all Game requests.')
    def get(self):
        return games_list_schema.dump(Game.find_all()), 200
    @games_ns.expect(gamerequest)
    @games_ns.doc("Create a Game request.")
    def post(self):
        game_json = request.get_json()
        game_data = game_schema.load(game_json)
        game_data.save_to_db()

        return game_schema.dump(game_data), 201
```

Comment: Handling enums in sqlalchemy is a bit of problematic, I would suggest you to simply handle it as a dictionary with key val pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to manage Enum fields for MySQL schema I suggest to use another table with backref to your eGameLevel. You can get rid of this whole fuss and also in future if you needed to add another option in your choice field you won't have to hardcode it.

Simply create a main table as Game and sub table as eGameLevel (with only one string field). You will be able to access choices from your Game table.

Whenever I get stuck I go to basics as mentioned in [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html).

Answer (score 1):

I made a small example just to test the serialization of an Enum

```py
from enum import Enum

import sqlalchemy as sa
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api, Namespace, Resource
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


class eGameLevel(str, Enum):
    BEGINNER = "Beginner"
    ADVANCED = "Advanced"


engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = "game"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    level = sa.Column(sa.Enum(eGameLevel), default=eGameLevel.BEGINNER, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Game(id={self.id}, level={self.level})"

    def json(self):
        data = {"id": self.id, "level": self.level}
        return data


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

g1 = Game(level=eGameLevel.BEGINNER)
g2 = Game(level=eGameLevel.ADVANCED)

session.add_all([g1, g2])
session.commit()
query_content = session.query(Game).all()

games_ns = Namespace("Game Requests", description="All Games Requests")


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


@api.route("/game")
class GameRequestsListAPI(Resource):
    @games_ns.doc("Get all Game requests.")
    def get(self):
        data = [x.json() for x in query_content]
        return data, 200


app.run(debug=True)
```

This example works and I think the serialization is possible due to the `str` in the Enum declaration: `class eGameLevel(str, Enum)`.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using Enum:

```
class eGameLevel(enum.Enum):
    BEGINNER    =   'Beginner'
    ADVANCED    =   'Advanced'
```

You can make use of dictionary:

```
eGameLevel = {"BEGINNER": 1, "ADVANCED": 2}
```

Then you can replace enum type for sql data model to String type as:

```
game_level= db.Column(db.Integer(), 
             default=eGameLevel["BEGINNER"], nullable=False)
```

And make appropriate checks using the defined dictionary throughout application. This will also solve issues with alembic as well for making db migrations.

You would also require modifying some of your python files. I would rather do it here directly, and then you can look up to modify them:

```
#Import at Resources
from flask import request
from app.models import Game, eGameLevel
```

Post Part:

```
    # For post part
    payload = request.json
    game_obj = Game(game_level=eGameLevel[payload["game_level"]], user_id=payload["user_id"]) 
    db.session.add(game_obj)
    db.session.commit()
```

Furthermore, I did not understand what the `from app.models import Gode` meant.

Comment: Please try it yourself. Its not working. It says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ADVANCED'".  If I choose "BEGINNER". With this error it doesn't let me even execute from Swagger.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat I only attempt to provide a concept to the solution and not of course an entire solution. If you see your request schema, `gamerequest` there the game_level is expected to be a String which should be Integer right with all the model changes performed

Comment: as I said you are giving wrong solution and you will find out if you will able to solve it by creating architecture yourself.